# Parse style properties in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an style properties string like below

```
var style='max-width: 125px; height: auto; object-fit: cover; width: 125px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'
```

properties can be any. I want to check if max-width includes, and if it includes it will be deleted. But I couldn't resolve problem

```
 var imgmaxwidth = style;

 if (imgmaxwidth.includes("max-width")) {
   self.$dialog.find('.note-image-attributes-style-maxwidth').val(value of string max-width);
 }
```

I want to take this max-width value and then delete this property from string.

In final string will be

```
height: auto; object-fit: cover; width: 125px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `imgmaxwidth` isn't a string, so `.includes` won't work. Just check to see if the desired property is not an empty string.

Comment: it is a string if condition is work i just need to get value from string

Comment: `imgInfo.style.maxWidth`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
var style = 'max-width: 125px; height: auto; object-fit: cover; width: 125px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'
var styleArr = style.split(';')
var res = styleArr.filter(function (value) { 
  return !value.includes('max-width'); 
});
style = res.join(';');
console.log(style);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You could just do `return !value.includes('max-width');`, the filter function should return `true` if the item should be included and `false` if the item should not be included. The reason that your codes works as is, is that when `value` does not include `max-width` it returns `value`, which is a non-empty string, thus it is truthy. When `value` includes `max-width` it does not explicitly return anything, so it implicitly returns `undefined`, which is falsy.

Answer (score -1):

```
var style = $('p').attr('style');
var parts = style.split(';');
var newstyle=[];
for (i=0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
    if (parts[i].split(':')[0].toLowerCase().trim() != 'max-width')
    {
        newstyle.push(parts[i]);
    }
}
$('p').attr( 'style', newstyle.join(';'));
```

I corrected for  cases that would be missed if leading or trailing white space, or case issues. (prompted with comments by @Useless Code)

Comment: This breaks if there is a space before `max-width` in the string, as there probably would be if `max-width` isn't the first item in the style. Instead of testing `!= 'max-width` I would use `if (parts[i].split(':')[0].match(/^\s*max-width/i))`.